# Java 8 Optional instead of if

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, option-type

I have problem with Optional and I don't know how to handle it.

```
public void check(String name) {
   if (name != null)
      doSomething(name);
   else 
      doMore();
}
```

How to change this if into Optional?

Comment: you dont! `Optional`s are not supposed to be passed into methods, they are only for returning optional values. Your code is perfectly fine as it is right now (might want to add a `@Nullable` annotation)

Comment: In this case you really can't, but if your else was `doSomething("");` then an `Optional<String> name` could be used like `doSomething(name.orElse(""));`

Comment: It might be better to take advantage of method overloading in this case, so that the check() method with no parameter calls doMore(), while the check() method with the @NonNull String name only accepts non-null Strings. Otherwise, follow either Eugene's or luk2302's suggestions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a very neat method for that, but present in jdk-9...

```
public void check(String name){
     Optional.ofNullable(name)
            .ifPresentOrElse(YourClass::doSomething, YourClass::doMore);
}
```

assuming `doSomething` and `doMore` are static methods... If not an instance should be used, like `this::doSomething` or `this::doMore`

Comment: I think it should be `this::doSomething` and `this::doMore`

Comment: I would say that is very far from *neat*. That code is longer and more obscure than the original one. While technically correct I would request it to be changed when seeing it in a Code Review.

Comment: @luk2302 interesting point, can't argue. I *would* code with an `Optional` btw, but that's just me

Comment: where does the method ifPresentOrElse is comming from?

Comment: first, up!! I think it is reasonable. and spring mvc controller also introduced `Optional` parameters. but from the point of the OP's view just do it with `if` statement is ok.

Answer (score 13):

While there certainly is a way to create the same code using `Optional`s (e.g. see Eugene's answer) you should not use `Optional`s here (imho).

Either you would get the `Optional` passed into your method which creates a overhead for the caller and does not really make sense looking at why / for what use case `Optional` was introduced.
Or you would create the `Optional` yourself inside the method. That is more "okay" but very cumbersome, obscures what is actually happening and I would request it to be changed if I came across it during a code review. Just compare the snippet using an `Optional` and your current code - your code is probably shorter in terms of characters, it is obvious what is happening. The only upside of using Optionals here is that it seems to become a one-liner which is firstly nothing that is more important than readability and furthermore it is something you could achieve without it anyway if you would add some braces.

---

Bottom line: Your code is perfectly fine as it is.

Comment: This is soooo debatable... There's no valid technical argument to reject @Eugene 's code i.e. in a review. It's just a matter of taste, both ways are OK. *You* say the functional way is less readable, but that might perfectly be because *you* are so used to imperative constructs that it looks weird or less expressive to you. Both ways are correct and clear *once you get used to functional constructs*. On the other hand, there's no reason to replace a clear, readable imperative construct by some clear, readable functional equivalent construct...

Comment: I have found exactly such code during a code review and I requested it to be changed exactly as you have written. Good to know not all Java programmers are putting java.util.Optional wherever theoretically possible!

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason to change your implementation. There is no way to do what you want **in java 8** with an Optional without having an if, while respecting the idea of not using 'map' for side-effects.

I mean, you could have

```
public void check(String name) {
    Optional<String> nameOpt = Optional.ofNullable(name);
    nameOpt.ifPresent(n -> doSomething(n));
    if (!nameOpt.isPresent()) {
        doMore();
    }
}
```

but that has no sense. [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-how-use-it) you have a good article what Optional tries to resolve (and hence for what it's meant to be used): mainly for return types. Other stuff is just overusing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid `if` statement by utilizing Java 8 `Optional.map()` and `Optional.orElseGet()` methods. Check following example:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

final class OptionalTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        check("test", str -> {
            System.out.println("Yay, string is not null!");
            System.out.println("It's: " + str);
        }, () -> {
            System.out.println("Crap, string is a null...");
            System.out.println("There is nothing for me to do.");
        });

        check(null, str -> {
            System.out.println("Yay, string is not null!");
            System.out.println("It's: " + str);
        }, () -> {
            System.out.println("Crap, string is a null...");
            System.out.println("There is nothing for me to do.");
        });
    }

    static void check(String str, Consumer<String> ifPresent, Runnable ifNotPresent) {
        Optional.ofNullable(str)
                .map(s -> { ifPresent.accept(s); return s; })
                .orElseGet(() -> { ifNotPresent.run(); return null; });
    }
}
```

It will produce following output:

```
Yay, string is not null!
It's: test
Crap, string is a null...
There is nothing for me to do.
```

Method `check` expects 3 parameters:

- a String (it may be `null`)
- a `Consumer` lambda expression that does something with this value and **does not mutate** input value.
- a `Runnable` lambda with no parameters to do something when input `String` is `null`.

Of course you could easily modify following method and then utilize the whole potential of `Optional` class, e.g.:

```
static String checkAndReturn(String str, Function<String, String> ifPresent, Supplier<String> ifNotPresent) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(str)
            .map(ifPresent)
            .orElseGet(ifNotPresent);
}
```

Then:

```
System.out.println(checkAndReturn("test", String::toUpperCase, () -> "no value"));
System.out.println(checkAndReturn(null, String::toUpperCase, () -> "no value"));
```

will produce following output:

```
TEST
no value
```

I hope it helps.